# How to use the windows7 bluetooth in java?

Tags: java, bluetooth

My java code:

```
    try {
        LocalDevice ld = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        System.out.println("Address:" + ld.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Name:" + ld.getFriendlyName());

        DiscoveryAgent agent = ld.getDiscoveryAgent();
    } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
    }
```

error :
**Native **Library bluecove_x64 not available****

i saw solution -> param : -d32
but

error
***Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
Java Result: 1***

my os is windows7 64bit and jdk jdk1.7.0_11 (64bit)

how use the windows7 bluetooth in java?(server)

(i use lib -> blueCove 63 - http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to load a x32 bit dll from a x64 bit context. Native libraries can only be loaded within the same bit depthness. Trying using a x32 bit version of Java instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you! :) i installed 32bit jdk(jdk-7u21-windows-i586)! good! :)